# jQuery error: Status: 'error'. Error code: 500 while performing an edit in jqgrid

Tags: jquery

```
navGrid('#pager',{view:false,del:true},
    {
                afterComplete: function(response){
                alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                    },
                    {
                        afterComplete: function(response){
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                    },
                    {
                        afterComplete: function(response){
                        alert(response.responseText);
                            }
                            }
  );
// alert(xhr.statusText);
```

Comment: are you get 500 internal server error?

Answer (score 0):

This means your server side code failed in some way, and possibly threw an exception. jQuery has nothing to do with the problem, unless you're supplying data that *will* crash the server. Even then, it's the server's fault.

Can you please provide more context?